# How do I find the size of a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm told that `show table status` is useful in finding the size of a database, but I get an unreadable mess.  Is there any way to alter this command to get less information, or is there another way to find the size of a database or table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two fields you want are.

- **Data_length**

  This is the size of the data within the table in bytes.
- **Index_length**

  This is the size of the table's index in bytes.

You can limit the output to one table with a database with.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename';
```

You can't remove the other columns from the output. You might find the output easier to read from a console by printing the output rows vertically. Just replace the "`;`" for "`\G`".

Answer (score 6):

I have a rather wild set of queries that would address this nicely. I wrote these about 2 years ago and they work just great. I still use them for reporting to clients.

Query to Give You Database Size Grouped By Storage Engine in MB

```
SELECT IFNULL(B.engine,'Total') "Storage Engine",         
  CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR('KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size",
  CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size",
  CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Table Size" 
FROM (
  SELECT engine,SUM(data_length) DSize,
    SUM(index_length) ISize,
    SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize 
  FROM information_schema.tables 
  WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')
    AND engine IS NOT NULL 
  GROUP BY engine WITH ROLLUP) B,
(SELECT 2 pw) A 
ORDER BY TSize;
```

Query to Give You Database Size Grouped By Database in MB

```
SELECT DBName,
  CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(SDSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Data Size",
  CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(SXSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Index Size",
  CONCAT(LPAD(FORMAT(STSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') "Total Size" 
FROM (
  SELECT IFNULL(DB,'All Databases') DBName,
  SUM(DSize) SDSize,
  SUM(XSize) SXSize,
  SUM(TSize) STSize 
  FROM (
    SELECT table_schema DB,
      data_length DSize,
      index_length XSize,
      data_length+index_length TSize 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema')) AAA 
    GROUP BY DB WITH ROLLUP
) AA,
(SELECT 2 pw) BB 
ORDER BY (SDSize+SXSize);
```

Query to Give You Database Size Grouped By Database and Storage Engine in MB

```
SELECT Statistic,DataSize "Data Size",
  IndexSize "Index Size",
  TableSize "Table Size" 
FROM (
  SELECT IF(ISNULL(table_schema)=1,10,0) schema_score,
    IF(ISNULL(engine)=1,10,0) engine_score,
    IF(ISNULL(table_schema)=1,'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',table_schema) schemaname,
    IF(ISNULL(B.table_schema)+ISNULL(B.engine)=2,
    "Storage for All Databases",
    IF(ISNULL(B.table_schema)+ISNULL(B.engine)=1,
    CONCAT("Storage for ",B.table_schema),
    CONCAT(B.engine," Tables for ",B.table_schema))) Statistic,
    CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.DSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') DataSize,
    CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.ISize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') IndexSize,
    CONCAT(LPAD(REPLACE(FORMAT(B.TSize/POWER(1024,pw),3),',',''),17,' '),' ',SUBSTR(' KMGTP',pw+1,1),'B') TableSize 
  FROM (SELECT table_schema,engine,
    SUM(data_length) DSize,
    SUM(index_length) ISize,
    SUM(data_length+index_length) TSize 
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('mysql','information_schema','performance_schema') 
      AND engine IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY table_schema,engine WITH ROLLUP) B,
    (SELECT 2 pw) A) AA 
ORDER BY schemaname, schema_score,engine_score;
```

All three queries have one thing in common: A simple SELECT query (SELECT 2 pw).

The pw stands for power, the exponent used against the number 1024. You can adjust the query to give you Database Sizes with different units:

```
(SELECT 0 pw) --reports the Database Size in Bytes
(SELECT 1 pw) --reports the Database Size in Kilobytes
(SELECT 2 pw) --reports the Database Size in Megabytes
(SELECT 3 pw) --reports the Database Size in Gigabytes
(SELECT 4 pw) --reports the Database Size in Terabytes
(SELECT 5 pw) --reports the Database Size in Petabytes (email me if you reach this size)
```

Give Them a Try !!!

Comment: Too bad I can't give you 2 points up. Thanks for this!

Comment: I have a new-and-improved algorithms in my DBA StackExchange post (http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8662/877). I added them 2015-01-16 14:46 EST. It handles all units (KB,MB,GB) without specifying it beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Found a script should do what you want -

http://www.modwest.com/help/kb6-199.html

```
<?

mysql_connect("db.modwest.com", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("yourdb");

$result = mysql_query("show table status");

$size = 0;
$out = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $size += $row["Data_length"];
    $out .= $row["Name"] .": ". 
               round(($row["Data_length"]/1024)/1024, 2) ."<br>\n";
}

$size = round(($size/1024)/1024, 1);

echo $out ."<br>\n";
echo "Total MySQL db size: $size";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the actual size the database takes up on disk just find the size of the data/dbname directory.

Comment: This is specifically for MyISAM tables

Answer (score 0):

Try this script:

```
SELECT 
    table_schema AS DataBase_Name
    ,ROUND(sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 /1024,1) AS OccupiedSize_inMB
    ,ROUND(sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024,1) AS FreeSpace_inMB 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
GROUP BY table_schema ;
```